# Why I didn't earn Populist badge?

Tags: discussion

Why didn't earn [Populist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) badge for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913676/xcode-5-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process/18918500#18918500)?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't have 11 votes or more votes.

Comment: Why it should have 11 votes?

Comment: The badge description says "more than 10". That means 11. So the minimum is 11 for the accepted answer and 23 for yours.

Comment: FWIW, the duplicate has *very* detailed information on the exact criteria it takes to get this badge.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the populist badge is

> Highest scoring answer that **outscored an accepted answer with score of
>   more than 10** by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple
>   times.

Note that it is the accepted answer that must have a score of 10 or more, not your answer

Comment: "more than 10". That means 11.

Comment: ah, ok hard to get for this one I think!

Comment: @hasan The gold ones always are

Comment: yeehaa, I just got 100 reputation on both sites for signing for this site :)

Comment: @hasan Every cloud has a silver lining! Enjoy your association bonus

Comment: Great say. if that what they say in english :) Thank you.